# how to handle fork() error in multi-process application with no exec*()

Tags: c, linux, fork, exit

I'm creating processes in loop with fork() function. The new processes do not call any function in the `exec*()` family; they just run their code and then exit using `exit()`. They can't fail.

But I don't know what to do if `fork()` fails and I have already created some new processes.
Do I have to use return or `exit()`? Do I have to use `killpg()` to kill created processes?
If `fork()` fails, I want to clean everything and exit program from main process.
Can someone give me a hint how to do this?

Comment: Calling `killpg(getpgrp(), SIGKILL)` followed by `exit(...)` or `return ...` should do the job.

Comment: Alternatively, `fork` failing isn't a fatal condition.  You are only going to fail if you reached your user limits or the system ran out of memory.  In both cases you can try and wait it out and collect your naturally dying children before trying again.

Comment: The parent process should keep track of which processes it created.  It can then kill those processes (loop and `kill()`) should something go wrong (like `fork()` failing).

Answer (score 3):

Calling `killpg(getpgrp(), SIGKILL)` followed by `exit(...)` or `return` ... should do the job.

For reference: [killpg()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/killpg.2.html), [getpgrp()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpgid.2.html)